# Convergence in probability of the means of a uniformly integrable sequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-integrability

> Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a uniformly integrable sequence of independent random variables with zero mean. 
>   Prove that
>   $1/n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \rightarrow0 $
>   in probability.

I tried to follow the proof of law of large numbers and transform it in order to prove this statement, but all such proofs use variance which may be not finite. Help please!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: I tried many different ways to solve this, but I am completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform integrability suggests a truncation argument. For $R$ a fixed positive number, define $X'_j:=X_j\chi_{\{|X_j|\leqslant R\}}-\mathbb E(X_j\chi_{\{|X_j|\leqslant R\}})$ and $X''_j:=X_j\chi_{\{|X_j|\gt R\}}-\mathbb E(X_j\chi_{\{|X_j|\gt R\}})$. Then $S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=\sum_{j=1}^n(X'_j+X''_j)$. We have 
$$\mathbb E|S_n|\leqslant \mathbb E\left|\sum_{j=1}^nX'_j\right|+n\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\mathbb E|X_j|\chi_{\{|X_j|\gt R\}}\leqslant\mathbb E \left|\sum_{j=1}^nX'_j\right|+n\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mathbb E(|X_k|\chi_{\{|X_k|\gt R\}}).$$
For the first term, we can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.